# How to calculate response time of each page , which contains multiple http samples in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, response-time

We have a application that contains 10 to 11 http samples in each page, we need to find the response time of each web page?, how to calculate? I have used transaction controller, but that gives sum of all samples response time, which in reality is very huge like 120000ms (120sec) , but wen manually checked application takes only 3 sec ?

Answer (score 1):

If real web browser executes these 10-11 requests **in parallel**, i.e. if they are [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests - you need to configure JMeter to do the same, it can be done using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter).

In this case you should be looking for the sum of **main request** and **longest** request.

You can install Parallel Sampler and Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for helping me out, will sure try this out.